# Spritekit circular ring (sprite node) passing through round wire (sprite node) - swift xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I want my sprite node (which is a circular ring like texture)  to pass through a round wire like texture.

The wire is placed vertically and fixed, and the ring is coming from the top and falling via gravity.

I want it to be placed initially like this as well [see picture].

Let me know if this is possible in SpriteKit.

[image]

Comment: sure, you need 2 half ring, one for the bottom and one for the top. zposition of the top must be greater then red node, zposition of the bottom must be lower.

Comment: You would need at least 3 parts actually, to handle the ring rotating

Comment: Do you want collision detection with that?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia .. thanks for reply. yes i got what you are saying ... but i also want collision detection with that as well. when ever sprite ring collides with sprint object. and will 2 half rings will act as one in any kind of movement?

Comment: The physics body does not need to reflect the sprite,  you could have a body shaped like a ring, and have the parts of your ring as children nodes of your main sprite

Comment: You could fuse the physics bodies `physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [topRing,bottomRing])`

Comment: Thanks both of you ... Let me try it.